# Вставка из Юникода в Python

Tags: python, utf-8, unicode, символы, интерпретатор

Господа, помогите пожалуйста с символами из Юникода.
Пробую вставить игральную карту из Юникода: `U+1F0A1`, но интерпретаторы (не установленные - т.к. нет возможности попробовать с домашнего компьютера, то пробую через Онлайн) печатают пустой квадрат или квадрат с вопросом.
Я пробовал вставлять: `"\U0001F0A1"` и `"\u1F0A1"` и даже просто копируя сам символ и вставляя внутрь кода - т. к. читал, что Python поддерживает напрямую символы из Юникода и не обязательно их писать в подобной кодировке.
Подскажите в чём проблема?

Comment: Пустой квадрат означает, что шрифт не содержит этого символа. Т.е. проблема не в Python, а чисто визуальная.

Comment: @insolor может ли отображаться данный символ на локальном установленном интерпретаторе, а не поддерживаться в онлайн версиях?

Comment: Может, если в консоли (или куда вы выводите) настроен шрифт с этим символом.

Comment: @insolor то есть в принципе, если я вас правильно понял, то - всё корректно и этот символ вводится правильно, просто не везде визуально отображается

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @insolor спасибо больше за пояснения)